# HTTPError: Forbidden urllib in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a HTTPError: Forbidden problem when using urllib to fetch some data from http://iconosquare.com
I searched a lot but none of answers solved my problem. Then I used firebug to find my browser's headers and copied all of them but can't solve this problem.
I can get data from php and then connect to php from python and get results from there but I can't use php in my project.
here is my code :

```
    url = 'http://iconosquare.com/'
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive',
   'DNT': '1',
   'Host':'iconosquare.com'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
       the_page = response.read()
       print(the_page)
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it returned data -- no error.

Comment: really?I can see this website on my browser but in python I have this error :(

Comment: I used Hotspotshield and it returned data. thanks @joelgoldstick

Comment: sounds like maybe you have a proxy in the way?